# How to concatenate two list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I concatenate two lists in Python with the same size?

Example:

```
    listname = ['jhon', 'maria', 'peter']
    listage = [18, 25, 14]
```

Expected outcome:

```
    finallist = [['jhon',18], ['maria',25], ['peter', 14]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> listname = ['jhon', 'maria', 'peter']
>>> listage = [18, 25, 14]
>>> zip(listname, listage)
<zip object at 0x000001E4734B6888>
>>> list(zip(listname, listage))
[('jhon', 18), ('maria', 25), ('peter', 14)]
```